# 'value' must be a single Unicode code point

Tags: python, selenium

```py
    def Check():
            afile = open("test.txt", "r")
            lines = afile.readlines()
            afile.close()

            for line in lines:
                test = line.split("\n")

                actions = ActionChains(driver)
                actions.send_keys(test)
                actions.perform()
                time.sleep(1)
                actions = ActionChains(driver)
                actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                actions.perform()
                time.sleep(1)
                actions = ActionChains(driver)
                actions.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_keys('z')
                actions.perform()
                time.sleep(1)
                actions = ActionChains(driver)
                actions.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_keys('z')
                actions.perform()
                time.sleep(1)
                actions = ActionChains(driver)
                actions.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_keys('z')
                actions.perform()
                Check()
Check()
```

Everytime i run this i get this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
> argument from invalid argument: 'value' must be a single Unicode code
> point

Comment: that's an odd one.  I would try just "Keys.CONTROL": https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html

Answer (score 0):

in that row you're setting list to test variable:

```
test = line.split("\n")
```

and pass to send_keys action:

```
actions.send_keys(test)
```

instead, try to put string value. And remove '\n' by rstrip function:

```
test = line.rstrip("\n")
```

Moreover, where are you attaching webdriver element to interact with?
I would suggest first moving to the element and then send_keys action, like that:

```
def Check():
    menu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="q"]')
    with open("test.csv", "r") as afile:
        lines = afile.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(menu).send_keys(line)
        actions.perform()
```